# How to find localised Microsoft Windows service names?

Tags: windows-7, services, localization

My Internet searched brought up several service names that are turned on by default on windows but might not be worth the resources they use. Specifically most of corporate/big network services can be disabled or turned to manual as they are never used on home computers.

The problem is that all the service names on the internet are written in English. My windows version is czech and Microsoft has localised absolutely everything (including console errors and other rare errors, such as stack overflow. Te last one sounds hilarious in my language). As well, service names are translated to czech and I have no idea how to find them using the English names. As my computer has lot of services installed, it's real pain to run through the list and try to guess, instead of just pressing the beginning letter of the service name and searching exact phrase.

Is there official or unofficial list of localised names and their English counterparts for Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft provides the Terminology Search in his Language Portal, it can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/search

Answer (score 0):

When you check the properties of any service in **services.msc**, the *Service name* (eg. "SensrSvc") is different from the *Display name* (eg. "Adaptive Brightness"). As far as I know only the latter is localized so you can try searching using the former.

Comment: What I see is both service name and service description localized (Win 7 Ultimate, Czech language).